# Ajuda com SubQuery em SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu tenho em meu sistema uma tabela chamada Agendas, esta tabela eh vinculada com outras tabelas Turma e Escola através das colunas `turmas_id` e `escola_id`. O que acontece eh que a coluna `turmas_id` não é uma foreign key relacionada mesmo recebendo o código da tabela Turma ela também pode receber 0, pois eu criei o 0 como representação para envio de mensagem no sistema para todas as Turmas da escola referente.

O que acontece é que agora preciso exibir os dados tanto para Turma existente como pra essa que recebe 0 referenciando todas Turma da Escola. Se eu usar JOIN para fazer a união das tabelas apenas códigos válidos serão retornados e o código 0 será ignorado pois não existe na tabela Turma.

Pensei em usar SubQuery para fazer isso, mas ainda não consegui fazer. Qual seria a melhor solução para fazer um SELECT retornando as turmas existentes na tabela Turma por exemplo, turma 15(terceiro ano) juntamente com a Turma que recebe 0 simbolizando todas ?

Estou tentando assim com JOIN, mas nesse caso os valores em 0 não são retornados.

```
$agendamentos = $this->Agenda->query("SELECT * FROM responsavel_alunos RespAlunos "
                    . "INNER JOIN pessoas Responsavel ON (Responsavel.id = RespAlunos.pessoas_id) "
                    . "INNER JOIN pessoas Aluno ON (Aluno.id = RespAlunos.pessoas_id1) "
                    . "INNER JOIN matriculas Matricula ON (Matricula.pessoas_id = Aluno.id) "
                    . "INNER JOIN turmas Turma ON (Turma.id = Matricula.turmas_id) "
                    . "INNER JOIN escolas Escola ON (Escola.id = Matricula.escolas_id) "
                    . "INNER JOIN agendas Agenda ON (Agenda.turmas_id = Turma.id) "
                    . "WHERE Responsavel.id = ? ORDER BY Agenda.created DESC "
                    , array($id)); //id do responsavel
```

**EDIT**

```
$agendamentos = $this->Agenda->query("SELECT * FROM responsavel_alunos RespAlunos "
                    . "INNER JOIN pessoas Responsavel ON (Responsavel.id = RespAlunos.pessoas_id) "
                    . "INNER JOIN pessoas Aluno ON (Aluno.id = RespAlunos.pessoas_id1) "
                    . "INNER JOIN matriculas Matricula ON (Matricula.pessoas_id = Aluno.id) "
                    . "LEFT JOIN turmas Turma ON (Turma.id = Matricula.turmas_id OR Turma.id = 0) "
                    . "INNER JOIN escolas Escola ON (Escola.id = Matricula.escolas_id) "
                    . "LEFT JOIN agendas Agenda ON (Agenda.turmas_id = Turma.id) "
                    . "WHERE Responsavel.id = ? ORDER BY Agenda.created DESC "
                    , array($id)); //id do responsavel
```

Imagem do model

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se você poder mandar a imagem da sua modelagem ia ajudar a mapear as tabelas e entender melhor o seu banco pra identificar se não tem nenhuma relação errada que você está fazendo na sua consulta.

Comment: @AdrianodeAbreuWanderley postei a imagem do modelo !

Comment: @FernandoPaiva, se deu certo, marque a resposta como aceita, assim poderá ajudar outros usuários.

Answer (score 3):

Faça conforme o Daniel Saraiva orientou, utilizando o `left join` . Veja sua consulta como deveria ficar. Eu testei aqui e deu certo.

```
SELECT * FROM responsavel_alunos RespAlunos
    INNER JOIN pessoas Responsavel ON (Responsavel.id = RespAlunos.pessoas_id)
    INNER JOIN pessoas Aluno ON (Aluno.id = RespAlunos.pessoas_id1)
    INNER JOIN matriculas Matricula ON (Matricula.pessoas_id = Aluno.id)
    LEFT JOIN turmas Turma ON (Turma.id = Matricula.turmas_id)
    INNER JOIN escolas Escola ON (Escola.id = Matricula.escolas_id)
    LEFT JOIN agendas Agenda ON (Agenda.turmas_id = Turma.id)
WHERE Responsavel.id = ?
ORDER BY Agenda.created DESC
```

Comment: Mesmo usando o LEFT JOIN as Turmas em Agendas que estão setadas como 0 não retornam. Eu preciso que retorne as Agendas com uma Turma válida(com id) e as que possuem Turma com id 0 em Agenda. Entendeu o que preciso ?

Comment: substituia `inner join` por `left join` em agendas. e tente novamente.

Answer (score 1):

use o `left join` que irá funcionar
exemplo

```
select USUARIO.USU_CODIGO, USU_NOME, GRU_CODIGO from USUARIO left join USUGRUPO ON USUARIO.USU_CODIGO = USUGRUPO.USU_CODIGO
```

Comment: Editei minha pergunta com o exemplo do SELECT que estou usando, tentei usar o LEFT mas ainda sim não consigo retornar os valores que contem Turma = 0

Answer (score 0):

Teste esse sql, usando o or turma.id = 0;

```
    SELECT * FROM responsavel_alunos RespAlunos
    INNER JOIN pessoas Responsavel ON (Responsavel.id = RespAlunos.pessoas_id)
    INNER JOIN pessoas Aluno ON (Aluno.id = RespAlunos.pessoas_id1) 
    INNER JOIN matriculas Matricula ON (Matricula.pessoas_id = Aluno.id) 
    INNER JOIN turmas Turma ON (Turma.id = Matricula.turmas_id or turma.id = 0) 
    INNER JOIN escolas Escola ON (Escola.id = Matricula.escolas_id) 
    INNER JOIN agendas Agenda ON (Agenda.turmas_id = Turma.id) 
     WHERE Responsavel.id = ? ORDER BY Agenda.created DESC;
```

Comment: no caso eu teria que usar no JOIN da Agenda pq o 0 esta apenas nessa tabela. Eu tentei usar `Agenda.turmas_id = Turma.id OR Agenda.turmas_id = 0` mas bagunça tudo os resultados. No caso pega aluno matriculado em outra Turma.

Comment: Tenta colocar o LEFT JOIN na tabela turmar e na tabela agenda, e deixa apenas o turmas.id = 0 no LEFT da turma.

Comment: Editei o Post com as informações que acho que você sugeriu. Se for como vc sugeriu a coluna `turmas_id` que possui o 0 retornam nulas sem a descricao da Agenda.